# Filter Non-null values from Tanstack table v8

Tags: reactjs, frontend, mern, react-table

i am making a truck management table in which a truck has a driver and an optional co-driver. i am making a driver count filter which have three options ("all", "single driver", "more drivers"). "all" shows all the rows. "single driver" shows the rows with only driver and no co-driver. "more drivers"  shows the rows with both the driver and co-driver. I'm not able to give a value to the "more drivers" selection such that it should select only those value where co-driver is not null. I'm sharing my code for table and driverFilter.

```
import {
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import tableData from "../../truckData";
import { Card, Typography } from "@material-tailwind/react";
import StatusCounter from "../TableCells/statusCounter";
import RouteText from "../TableCells/RouteText";
import ManageTruckButton from "../TableCells/ManageTruckButton";
import DriverFilter from "../TableFilters/TruckTableFilter/DriverFilter";

const columns = [
  {
    accessorKey: "truckNumber",
    header: "Truck Number",
    cell: (props) => <p>{props.getValue()}</p>,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "driver",
    header: "Driver",
    cell: (props) => <p>{props.getValue()}</p>,
  },
  {
    id: "co-driver",
    accessorFn: (row) => (row["co-driver"] ? row["co-driver"] : null),
    header: "Co-Driver",
    enableColumnFilter: true,
    cell: (props) => <p>{props.getValue()}</p>,
  },
  {
    id: "route",
    header: "Route",
    cell: RouteText,
  },
  {
    id: "status",
    header: "Status",
    cell: StatusCounter,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "loadNumber",
    header: "Load Number",
    cell: (props) => <p>{props.getValue()}</p>,
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "id",
    header: "Action",
    cell: ManageTruckButton,
  },
];

function TruckTable() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(tableData);
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState([]);
  const truckTable = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    state: {
      columnFilters,
    },
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h1>TRUCK TABLE</h1>
      <DriverFilter
        columnFilters={columnFilters}
        setColumnFilters={setColumnFilters}
      />
      <Card className="h-full m-5">
        <table
          className="w-full min-w-max table-auto text-left"
          width={truckTable.getTotalSize()}
        >
          <thead>
            {truckTable.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                  <th
                    key={header.id}
                    className="border-b border-blue-gray-100 bg-blue-gray-50 p-4"
                    width={header.getSize()}
                  >
                    <Typography
                      variant="small"
                      color="blue-gray"
                      className=" leading-none font-bold"
                    >
                      {header.column.columnDef.header}
                    </Typography>
                  </th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {truckTable.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
              <tr key={row.id} className=" border-b-2 border-b-gray-500">
                {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                  <td
                    key={cell.id}
                    width={cell.column.getSize()}
                    className="p-2"
                  >
                    {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                  </td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}

export default TruckTable;
```

This is the code for table and below is the code for the filter.

```
import { Option, Select } from "@material-tailwind/react";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function DriverFilter({ columnFilters, setColumnFilters }) {
  const changeDriverCountHandler = (e) => {
    switch (e) {
      case "all":
        setColumnFilters((prev) => {
          if (!prev) {
            return [];
          }
          const counts = prev.find((filter) => filter.id === "co-driver");
          if (counts) {
            return prev.filter((filter) => filter.id !== "co-driver");
          }
        });
        break;
      case "singleDriver":
        setColumnFilters((prev) => {
          if (prev) {
            const counts = prev.find((filter) => filter.id === "co-driver");
            if (!counts) {
              return [...prev, { id: "co-driver", value: null }];
            } else {
              return prev
                .filter((filter) => filter.id !== "co-driver")
                .concat({
                  id: "co-driver",
                  value: null,
                });
            }
          } else {
            return [{ id: "co-driver", value: null }];
          }
        });
        break;
      case "moreDrivers":
        setColumnFilters((prev) => {
          const counts = prev.find((filter) => filter.id === "co-driver");
          if (!counts) {
            return [...prev, { id: "co-driver", value: "" }];
          } else {
            return prev
              .filter((filter) => filter.id !== "co-driver")
              .concat({
                id: "co-driver",
                value: "",
              });
          }
        });
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
    console.log("newColumnFilters", columnFilters);
  };
  return (
    <div className="flex gap-2">
      <Select
        label="Driver Count"
        defaultValue="all"
        onChange={(e) => {
          changeDriverCountHandler(e);
        }}
      >
        <Option value="all" className="flex items-center gap-2">
          All
        </Option>
        <Option value="singleDriver" className="flex items-center gap-2">
          Single Driver
        </Option>
        <Option value="moreDrivers" className="flex items-center gap-2">
          More Drivers
        </Option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DriverFilter;
```

I tried using "" as the value for the "more drivers" but it is considering it as a separate filter and not returning any value.